# How to Deploy Cross plot-form application in iOS Device for testing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

i am very much new to xamarin development,i have created one cross platform application in Windows10 with VS2017 and it is working fine in both iOS and android simulaters, And i am able to get .apk file for android to install in android device to test.

But now i need to deploy this application in iOS Device to test. can any one give steps to achieve this.

Best Regards,
Srinivas.

Answer (score 1):

You Need to use one of these 3 methods Xamarin gives you to do so.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/app-store-distribution/

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/in-house-distribution/

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/ad-hoc-distribution/

Comment: Thanks Luis for replying, Actually i have Developed app in Windows visual studio 2017, even those above methods will work?

Comment: Yes, as long as you meet the [Windows Requirements](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/#Windows_Requirements) you are good to go

Comment: Thanks Luis for the quick reply, i will check with the Windows Requirements